# tosca to change a buffered number like 0000123 to 123

Tags: tosca

My goal is to change a buffered number with many leading zeros (like 00000000123) to only the number without the leading zeros (123).
Do you have any ideas how I could do that?

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the DataType to Numeric, while setting the buffer
[setting numeric buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S82c.png)
Buff1 in my case will have leading zeros, Buff2 will be without them

Answer (score 0):

If the target machine has MS Excel installed, then create another buffer as following

Excel installed
Name: BufferedIntegerValue Value: {CALC[{B[BufferedNumber]}]}

Excel not installed
Name: BufferedIntegerValue Value: {MATH[{B[BufferedNumber]}]}

from TOSCA version 13.x manual: https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1330/en/content/tbox/calculations.htm?Highlight=math%20function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).